# $anchorScroll.yOffset not working for ngIncluded content

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I've got a page with Angular that has some components that can be opened and closed. These components are included via `ngInclude`. I would like to be able to click on a navbar menu item and scroll to the content within the `ngIncluded` divs. This works so far, but the `$anchorScroll.yOffset` value does not seem to impact the way the `anchorScroll` works, which means that the content from the `div`s with `ngInclude` are partially hidden behind the navbar.

Anybody else experience this?

Comment: Yes and I couldn't figure it out. Had 2 divs. Selecting an item on the left one populated the right one. Couldn't get the right one to scroll properly. Switched to a jquery method instead.

Comment: I think this might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128282/angular-scroll-div-on-button-click/32128372#32128372 AFAIK, if you want to scroll divs, you shouldn't use anchorScroll since that scrolls the page. Look at the plunkr in the page linked.